# Microsoft Codename?

Tags: iis, oslo

Today I was walking at the [MSDN Forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/categories) and I see two very strange forums, [Microsoft Codename 'Oslo'](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/oslo/threads) and [Microsoft Codename 'Dublin'](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/dublin/threads), what is this? what they do?

Comment: This seems a fairly pointless question to me as the answer to it can quite easily be found by following the links that you have posted and reading the fairly obvious FAQ links.

Comment: dublin-core != Microsoft Dublin. Retagged.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Oslo: http://www.microsoft.com/soa/products/oslo.aspx
- Dublin: http://www.microsoft.com/NET/Dublin.aspx

Comment: Says on my link that Dublin is the next Windows Server release.

Comment: I believe Dublin are essentially extensions to IIS. I don't believe it is a whole new release to Windows per se. It provides facilities to track, monitor correlate WCF/WF services. It builds upon WAS. Unless I am mistaken?

Comment: The linked content on "Dublin" is stone-age. Jon is right. It'll be an extension to IIS/WAS enabling more reliable services.

Comment: And the comment on Oslo is even worse. When it was announced, it was for SOA. But that was back in 2007.

Comment: Removed comments - I took them from the websites anyway.

Answer (score 0):

**Oslo**

Doug Purdy, one of the pionieers in what they call "Oslo" regrets havin' kept the name for so long.

Read more here:

- Microsoft: [Sept 08 - What is Oslo](http://www.douglaspurdy.com/2008/09/06/what-is-oslo/) and [Aug 09 - On Oslo **FEATURED**](http://www.douglaspurdy.com/2009/08/17/on-oslo/)
- Indipendent (me): [Okt 08 - What Oslo is and is not](http://startbigthinksmall.wordpress.com/2008/11/07/post-pdc-again-what-is-oslo-m-mgrammar-quadrant-repository-textual-dsls-dsl-tools-uml-modeling-november-2008/) and [Sept 09 - Updates on Oslo](http://startbigthinksmall.wordpress.com/2009/08/19/updates-on-what-oslo-is-and-quadrant-not-is-september-2009/)

**Dublin**
There hasn't really been much publishing around Dublin. The community hoped for an answer to "What is the Java EJB Application Server-Pandon in .NET?".

Anyway, we expect more to come by this years PDC. Have a look at the sessions on Dublin here:[Sessions on Dublin](http://microsoftpdc.com/Sessions#?term=dublin)

One of them has following text, which summarizes the plans, I guess:

> .NET 4 and “Dublin” provide new application hosting, tracking, and persistence capabilities. Learn the benefits of different hosting options and how to choose the right option for your scenario. Learn …

From what I've heard so far it will be an extension for IIS that works with WAS and will host WCF services in a better way, than *.svc-Files do today.