# What is Dublin and how does it relate to WCF?

Tags: .net, wcf, iis, .net-4.0

Going through some WCF hosting questions on StackOverflow, I've seen Dublin mentioned a few times as a technology from Microsoft that is forthcoming. It's only alluded to and not actually defined though. Can someone give me a good explanation of what Dublin is? Also, what is its release status and is it going by a different name now?

(Here's an example: it's mentioned in the comments to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560619/iis-wcf-service-hosting-vs-windows-service/1560784#1560784) answer)

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/net/dublin.aspx

Comment: yeah, that name conflict is making it hard to search for

Comment: if you know (or suspect) it's a microsoft thing then always try to add the word `codename` to your google search. Try it out with "codename dublin" and see what a difference it makes.

Comment: I'm not having trouble finding the marketing blurbs from Microsoft. I'm looking for an actual explanation, but thanks for the Google tip!

Comment: also see: [Microsoft Codename?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1660911/1281433)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dublin is the codename for [Windows Server AppFabric](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/ee695849.aspx).  It is a framework for hosting applications that aren't specifically web-based within IIS, taking advantage of all the infrastructure provided. Essentially, it provides hosting services to developers that are more generalized than those provided by ASP.NET.